# Regarding Time change in Katok's book

Tags: dynamical-systems, orbit-equivalence

I have something that is driving me crazy for some while. In Katok and Hasselblat's book, Introduction to Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems, on page 65 they go through a discussion about time change. On page 65  they write an equation (2.2.5). I am able to drive very similar relations between $\beta$ and $\alpha$ but never the less, no matter what I do, I can't drive the exact same relation they get in (2.2.6). Could someone please tell me how they do get to relation (2.2.5)? I have a feeling that they messed up something but I'm not quite sure.

---

I now go through what I do. By assumption, we are doing a time change with the reparametrization $\alpha$ to get a flow $\psi^t := \varphi^{\alpha(t,\ .)}$. Also by assymption, $\psi^t$ and $\varphi^t$ are conjugate by the same $h$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
    h\varphi^th^{-1} = \psi^t; \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Hence for any $x$
$$
    h(\varphi^t(x)) = \psi^t(h(x)).
$$
But
\begin{align}
    \psi^t(h(x))
    &=
    \varphi^{\alpha(t,\ h(x))}h(x)
    \\
    &=
\varphi^{\alpha(t,\ h(x)) + \beta(x)}(x)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
   h(\varphi^t(x))
    &=
    \varphi^{\beta(\varphi^t(x))}(\varphi^t(x))
    \\
    &=
\varphi^{\beta(\varphi^t(x)) + t}(x).
\end{align}

Therefore $\beta(\varphi^t(x)) + t = \beta(x) + \alpha(t, h(x))$, i.e.
$$
\alpha(t, h(x)) - t = \beta(\varphi^t(x)) - \beta(x).
$$

I really suspect that $\alpha(t, h(x)) = \alpha(t, x)$ so I think what they wrote is wrong but I might be mistaken. Anyways, differentiating with respect to $t$ gives:

$$
a(h(x)) - 1 = \xi(x)(\beta); \quad \forall x
$$
or to make things shorter,
$$a \circ h - 1 = \xi(\beta).$$
This is also different from what they have:
$$
a - 1 = \xi(\beta).
$$

However (I'm not sure) that I once proved $a$ and $\beta$ are invariant under iterations of $h$ which means that in that case the equation they have is also correct. But nevertheless i don't really see how they get directly into it.

Comment: You are quite right. Indeed, it is common knowledge for quite some time now that their derivation and formulas concerning time changes are wrong.

Comment: Really? Thanks a lot! It was driving me crazy!!!! :-)